# Prism-map with QGIS (2.5 D)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, cartography

I am trying to make a Prism Map with the 2.5 D Renderer with latest QGIS. Unfortunately the map does not look like expected. The prism for the boundary with the highest value looks "inverted":

[image]

Enclosed a prism-map as it should look (not made with QGIS):

[image]

Here is the link to the used shapefile (zip. 24 kb)
https://trinko.eu/Downloads/BundeslaenderBRPproKopf.zip

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem has to do with the rendering order.
I managed to get a good result by:

1. selecting the 2.5D symbology for the polygons with the desired options;
2. changing it back to a single symbol, which retains the 2.5D style;
3. tick the control entity rending order (*I don't know its exact English name, since mine is in Romanian*) which can be found at the bottom of the symbology panel. For its options, I deleted the lengthy expression and added the attribute `2020`, with ascending as the option.

[image]

Now, the symbology seems to accurately reflect the data.

[image]